# Why does my comment show 41 "license: CC by SA 4.0"? Are all comments protected under copyright?

Tags: discussion, comments, licensing, creative-commons

Why does my comment show this?

> 41 license: CC by SA 4.0

Are all comments protected under "creative commons" copyright? What does 41 mean? Why not 1 license -  why 41?

[image: name highlight under "Pretty Girl" followed by "41"]

Comment: Try reading the full paragraph. [41 mins ago](//i.stack.imgur.com/JSe5o.png), not 41 licenses. The timestamp has nothing to do with the license; it’s just a convenient place to put a permalink on and since it’s useful for citations, that’s where the license goes. See [Creative Commons Licensing UI and Data Updates](/q/347758/289905). Nothing about your comment shows _“41 license: cc by sa 4.0”_. The tooltip shows _“2021-11-30 03:18:55Z, License: CC BY-SA 4.0”_.

Comment: What actually happened? Did the mouse cursor or your finger ***obscure*** *"mins ago"* in "41 mins ago" ***and*** obscured something like  *"2021-11-30 09:24:57Z."* in the tooltip's *"2021-11-30 09:24:57Z. License: CC BY-SA 4.0"*? What did you actually do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're seeing is unrelated to the license. It's the number of minutes since you posted a comment, but the next part is on the next line:

[image: 50 // minutes ago]

Yes, the comment is posted under CC by SA 4.0. You can see the license by hovering over that timestamp in grey, or by viewing the timeline for the post, which is the button under the downvote arrow. All user content is [licensed under CC BY SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing): 2.5, 3.0, or 4.0.

You don't usually need to worry about the license. When you use someone's words or ideas, say who you got it from and link to the post. Use quote marks if it's an exact quote. (It only gets more complicated than that if you're copying content for use outside Stack Exchange.)

Comment: So, every comment is protected under CC by SA 4.0 by default? Even this comment?

Comment: @PrettyGirl Recent comments, yes. Older comments will be CC by SA 3.0 or CC by SA 2.5.

Comment: @PrettyGirl _“Even this comment?”_ — Does the timeline or the title text (when hovering) say _“License: CC BY-SA 4.0”_?

Comment: @SebastianSimon yeah, name hovering says it. Now I get it.